# Javascript 3D rotate independent object within other object

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my program, I have four `Physijs.BoxMesh(...)`, and they are all added to an independent object. I want to rotate the four physics boxes, but once they are all added to the 5th object, they won't rotate. Is there any way to rotate the objects that are contained?

**EDIT** : Here's all of my code:

```
<body></body>
<script src="http://gamingJS.com/Three.js"></script>
<script src="http://gamingJS.com/physi.js"></script>
<script src="http://gamingJS.com/ChromeFixes.js"></script>

<script>
  // Physics settings
  Physijs.scripts.ammo = 'http://gamingJS.com/ammo.js';
  Physijs.scripts.worker = 'http://gamingJS.com/physijs_worker.js';

  // This is where stuff in our game will happen:
  var scene = new Physijs.Scene({ fixedTimeStep: 2 / 60 });
  scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3( 0, -100, 0 ));

  // This is what sees the stuff:
  var width = window.innerWidth,
      height = window.innerHeight,
      aspect_ratio = width / height;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect_ratio, 1, 10000);
  // var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
  //   -width/2, width/2, height/2, -height/2, 1, 10000
  // );

  camera.position.z = 500;
  scene.add(camera);

  // This will draw what the camera sees onto the screen:
  var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';

  // ******** START CODING ON THE NEXT LINE ********

  var m1 = new Physijs.BoxMesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 150, 20), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x000000}));
  var m2 = new Physijs.BoxMesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 150, 20), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x000000}));
  var m3 = new Physijs.BoxMesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 150, 20), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x000000}));
  var m4 = new Physijs.BoxMesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 150, 20), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x000000}));
  var ground = new Physijs.BoxMesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(5e2, 10, 5e2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x0000ff}), 0);  

  var tars = new Physijs.BoxMesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());

  m1.__dirtyPosition = true;
  m1.position.x = -30;
  m2.__dirtyPosition = true;
  m2.position.x = -10;
  m3.__dirtyPosition = true;
  m3.position.x = 10;
  m4.__dirtyPosition = true;
  m4.position.x = 30;
  ground.__dirtyPosition = true;
  ground.position.y = -300;

  tars.add(m1);
  tars.add(m2);
  tars.add(m3);
  tars.add(m4);

  scene.add(tars); // If I add Tars the Avatar, below at the document add listener, m1.setAngularVelocity(...) will not actually rotate the m1 block

  scene.add(ground);

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 13:
        m1.setAngularVelocity(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
        break;

      case 100:
        m2.setAngularVelocity(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
        break;

      case 101:
        m3.setAngularVelocity(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
        break;

      case 102:
        m4.setAngularVelocity(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
        break;
    }
  });

  // Animate motion in the game
  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  animate();

  // Run physics
  function gameStep() {
    scene.simulate();
    // Update physics 60 times a second so that motion is smooth
    setTimeout(gameStep, 1000/60);
  }
  gameStep();
</script>
```

Comment: @2pha I have now added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work because a Physijs mesh has properties that cannot be inherited from a parent Object3D. For example, an Object3D cannot have angular momentum.

The correct way to get the behavior you want is by using [Physijs constraints](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/wiki/Constraints).